# Printing SQL table header names via PHP

Tags: php

I have this. I'm trying to capture the SQL table header name from PHP. This works fine for me.

However I'm struggling to tune this to echo the whole list of table header names except one or two which I dont need to print.

Suppose the names of column number 10 and 15 do not need to be printed how do I tweak my attempt?

Here goes the the code thus far.

```
     // DB1 Connection

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sal_vol;"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db1,$sql); 
$i = 0; 

while($i<mysqli_num_fields($result)) 
{ 
  $meta=mysqli_fetch_field($result); 
  echo $i.".".$meta->name."<br />"; 

  $i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($i<mysqli_num_fields($result)) 
{ 
  if ($i == 10 || $i == 15) continue;
  $meta=mysqli_fetch_field($result); 
  echo $i.".".$meta->name."<br />"; 

  $i++; 
}
```

Comment: this stops the execution at number 10. My requirements actually is to proceed from there without echoing 10 and also 15 when it gets there

Comment: @mohanamila No that doesn't stops the while, it only jumps over to the next iteration. [PHP.net: continue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: well it does in my case. shows only up to 9 and then i get this.. Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xa......